# MySQL - Create table with a specific TIMESTAMP format

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to create a table with a specific TIMESTAMP format (HH:mm:00) where I need to fix sec to 00.

```
CREATE TABLE `published` (
  `time_pub` timestamp() NULL DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the way the timestamp is stored. Only the way it is presented in your select statements.

Another solution would be to store the data in a `hour` and `minute` column having an integer data type.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't specify the time format when create table, you can use `date_format` function in `MySQL` to fix the second part to 00 when insert data to database.

```
insert into TABLE_NAME values (date_format(now(), '%H:%m:00'));
```